# Acquire MP7A1 for MOH 360

Tags: xbox-360, medal-of-honor

According to the [wikia page](http://medalofhonor.wikia.com/wiki/MP7A1), "It is available instantly to users that pre-ordered the Tier 1/Limited Edition of the game".  How do you get it if you haven't pre-ordered the Limited Edition and it's no longer available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this official EA [blog post](http://www.medalofhonor.com/blog/2010/07/medal-honor-limited-edition)/press release (emphasis mine):

> Today Electronic Arts Inc. (NASDAQ: ERTS) announced a Limited Edition version of Medal of Honor that will grant players **exclusive access** to the MP7, a unique weapon utilized by Tier 1 Operators in the field.

In addition to exclusive access to this gun, the limited edition also unlocks other weapons without having to rank up first (specifically the TOZ-194 and 870MC2 shotguns).

Other resources, including this [guide](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/113/1130398p1.html) seem to confirm that the only way to-date to unlock this weapon in multiplayer is to have purchased the limited edition.

For most people, this means the gun is inaccessible in multiplayer.